# How to properly use setitem from dict in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am attempting to have user input add to a dictionary.  When attempting to add the user input to the dictionary, I receive the following error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'setitem'.

Here is my code:

```
states = {
    'Sao Paulo': 'SP',
    'Minas Gerias': 'MG',
    'Bahia': 'BA'
}

cities = {
    'SP': 'Sao Paulo',
    'MG': 'Ouro Preto',
    'BA': 'Salvador'
}
print('-'*10)
for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):
    print(f"{state} is abbreviated as: {abbrev}")

print('-'*10)
print("The poppin cities in Brazil are: ")
for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):
    print(f"{cities[abbrev]}, {abbrev} ")

def addToStates():
    print("Here, we will add another State to the dictionary.")
    state = input("Enter State: ")
    abbrev = input("Enter Abbreviation: ")
    states.setitem(state, abbrev)

def printCitiesStates():
    print('-'*10)
    print("The poppin cities in Brazil are: ")
    for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):
        print(f"{cities[abbrev]}, {abbrev} ")

def options():
    print("1. Add States")
    print("2. Print Cities and States")
    print("3. Exit")
    print("\n")
    choice = input("Enter choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        addToStates()
        options()
    elif choice == "2":
        printCitiesStates()
        options()
    elif choice == "3":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Not an Option")
        options()

options()
```

Comment: just do `states[state] = abbrev`